# Relative "res/values" folder in Android to scale styles based on screen size and resolution?

Tags: android, android-resources

I wonder if it's possible to have a folder such as `res/values-small` or `res/values-hdpi` in the same way that it's possible for the `layout` folder? I'm thinking about styles that should automatically scale depending on the screen resolution and size.

Or do I simply create a separate style for other resolutions in the same `values/style.xml` file?

Comment: you already have values-large, values-v11 and values-v14 folders

Comment: ^Hm, I don't see a `values-large` built in to my project. Would you know why's that? My target API level is currently 16 (Jelly Bean).

Comment: values-large is an obsolete pattern, you should use values-hdpi or values-xhdpi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are right all the names you mentioned are valid. To experiment more with different filenames use ADT.  [image: ADT Screen with qualifiers]

Comment: Just to add to the convo: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html has a list if you like doing it the fun way